# Is it possible to pass complete dict outside the loop to another dict

Tags: python

I am trying to pass the dictionary outside the loop having all the results inside it. Is it possible?

My Code:

```
file_name = input('Enter a file name: ')
f = open(file_name, 'r')
data = f.readlines()
final_data = []

for line in data:
      values = line.split()
      read_line = dict({
                'vertex': values[0],
                'visited': values[1],
                'letter': values[2],
                'neighbors': values[3]
                })
      final_data.append(read_line)

print(final_data['vertex'])
```

**Error**
    TypeError: list indices must be integers, not str

The reason it is showing error that it has converted the dict to list. Now when i use .copy() to copy the dict to final_data, it only prints the first line in the file. I somehow want to copy the whole dict as i need to access different key=>values later in the code.

**My input file**

```
1 0 A 2,3 // 1 = vertex || 0 = visited || A = letter || 2,3 = neighbors
2 0 B 1,4,5
3 0 C 1,2
4 0 D 2,5
5 0 E 2,4
```

I know lists only take Integers but i need dict somehow.

Comment: _"The reason it is showing error that it has converted the dict to list."_ That doesn't sound right to me. When you do `final_data = []`, that means `final_data` is a list to begin with. No conversion takes place.

Comment: Why don't you use the "letters" or "indices" (first column) of the vertices as the corresponding dictionary keys and create only one dict instead of a list of dicts?

Comment: @Kevin: I tried copying the orignal dict by using .copy and removed final_data = [] from the top but it copied the first line only. I want the whole dict to be copied and be printed outside the loop. I need suggestions for that.

Comment: @Hyperboreus: Can you please elaborate? Did not understand you clearly

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, you can make this much neater:

```
final_data = []
fields = ["vertex", "visited", "letter", "neighbours"]
with open(file_name, 'r') as f:
    for line in f:
        final_data.append(dict(zip(fields, line.strip().split(' ')))
```

Secondly, your `final_data` is a list of dictionaries, with each dictionary in the list holding the content of one line from the file:

```
final_data = [{"vertex": "1", "visited": "0", 
               "letter": "A", "neighbours": "2,3"}, 
              {...}, 
              ...]
```

So to get the first item's vertex, you need to index the list *and* key the dictionary:

```
final_data[0]["vertex"]
```

Answer (score 2):

You've got a *list* of dictionaries (you kept appending to it for every line in the file), not a single dictionary. Hence

```
print final_data[0]['vertex']
```

should work and would show the vertex from the first line. If you wanted to print all of them you could do something like:

```
print [ d['vertex'] for d in final_data ]
```

or iterate over the final_data list:

```
for d in final_data:
    print d['vertex'] + '\n'
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to access `final_data` as a dictionary, but you declared it as a list with the `[]` notation.  Either you need to access it in a list-like manner, or when you add your `read_line` dicts to the `final_data` dict than you need to provide a key with which they could be looked up

Comment: Are you trying to say that i have give keys again to the new dict i.e final_data? 

Can you give me an example?

Comment: You are appending a dictionary to a list.  So when you try to access final_data, how do you know what value you want?  Do you want the 1st dict that you put in? The second?  Then you'd be accessing as final_data[0], final_data[1], etc.

Answer (score 0):

What about something like this, where you set the dictionary key to vertex value?

```
final_data = dict()
for line in data:
      values = line.split()
      read_line = dict({
                'visited': values[1],
                'letter': values[2],
                'neighbors': values[3]
                })
      final_data[values[0]] = read_line

print(final_data[1])
```